# Separate image as a two part in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

**I have a that kind of images**

[image: Image1] 
[image: Image2]

As images shown, image mainly have a two part.
upper and lower.

I want to separate them.

**In the first try, I implements using K-meas algorithms.**

`In[2]: kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(...
np.asarray(np.where(finalImage == 255)).T)`

It is works on Image1 cases that upper and lower have a almost same amount of dots. But isn't works at Image 2.

**After than I use cv2.findContours** **to get maximum area 2 contours**

```
im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(Img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    # get first contour
    maxContour = 0
    for contour in contours:
        contourSize = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if contourSize > maxContour:
            maxContour = contourSize
            maxContourData0 = contour

    # get second contour
    if contours.__len__() != 1:
        maxContour = 0
        for contour in contours:
            contourSize = cv2.contourArea(contour)
            if contourSize > maxContour and np.sum(np.subtract(contour[0:5],maxContourData0[0:5])) != 0:
                maxContour = contourSize
                maxContourData1 = contour

    mask = np.zeros_like(Img)
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, [maxContourData0], 1)
    if contours.__len__() != 1:
        cv2.fillPoly(mask, [maxContourData1], 1)

    finalImage = np.zeros_like(Img)
    finalImage[:, :] = np.multiply(Img, mask)

    cv2.imshow('final', finalImage)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But it sometimes goes one contour not 2...

is there any get two blob **compulsively?**

Comment: If the actual size of the blobs are not of importance but only the relative size, you could try applying erosion before you extract the blobs, it might help remove the connection between the two blobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and use [`connectedComponents`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gac2718a64ade63475425558aa669a943a), but note that you should set `connectivity = 4` and not `8` as the default.

Comment: What is meaning of connetivity?

Comment: @JungseokCho Connectivity defines the way the underlying grid-graph is constructed: 8-connect means every pixel is connected to all its 8 neighbors, while 4-connect means a pixel is only connected to the four pixel above, below to its lest and to it's right.

Comment: Note that the two segments in your example are touching each other "diagonally": that is they are considered connected with 8- connect, but are separated considering 4-connect

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the running time, you may try spectral clustering.

K-means doesn't work for this problem because it implicitly assumes that the clusters are spherical, while spectral clustering cares more about connectivity. The bad news is that it's much slower than K-means.

Below is my implementation using [sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering):

```
t0 = time.time()
spectral = cluster.SpectralClustering(n_clusters=2, affinity='rbf', n_init=3)
spectral.fit(pts)
t1 = time.time()
print(t1-t0)
```

Output:

```
19.5850000381
```

[image]

Comment: @JungseokCho It's in seconds.

Comment: Spectral clustering has a proven issue with clusters of different scales. You should use it carefully in your examples.